# Meanings of ip address notation [::]:[someport]

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6

what does this ip address notation means `[::]:[4443]`.

Comment: `[::]:[4443]` looks like a typo. It should have said `[::]:4443`

Answer (score 22):

`[::]` indicate all ipv6 addresses. 4443 is a port number. So if a service is bound to `[::]:4443` it'll be listening to all ipv6 addresses available in your system. It's similar to listening `0.0.0.0` for ipv4.

Some services bind to all IPs available (including ipv4) while binding to `[::]`. Strictly speaking `[::]` indicates ipv6 only. As per ipv6 writing convention, one consecutive block of `0's` in an ipv6 address can be replaced with `::`. Considering ipv6 is 128 bits the address `::` is `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` in expanded hexadecimal form.

Comment: s/one contentious block/a contiguous group/ or /a consecutive group/. v4 addresses are mapped into v6 (at ::ffff:0000:0000/96) so listening on :: can accept both v6 and v4 if the implementation chooses, usually called 'single-stack'; only 'dual-stack' implementations require separate listens on :: and 0.0.0.0

Comment: so what you are saying is that 4443 is listening port for all ipv4 and ipv6 addresses.

Answer (score 10):

It's a bind designation to port 4443 of all interfaces that support IPv6. It is equivalent to `[0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:4443`.